# How to hide property inherited Interface in a class

Tags: c#, interface

I have two classes Inherited from ICart interface

When I create an object from this classes I want  only Guest class show me IsInfoExist property. How am I gonna do that?

```
ICart cart = new Guest();
bool c = cart.IsInfoExist //it's ok

ICart cart = new Member();
cart.IsInfoExist not ok.
```

Actually I dont want never appear on intellinsense but Interface force me to show Member IsInfoExist property

```
class Guest:ICart
{
    public bool IsInfoExist
    {
        get { return Session["guest_info"] != null; }
    }

   public void GetCart()
   {

   }
}

class Member:ICart
{
    //Hide this on intellinsense always!
    public bool IsInfoExist
    {
        get { return false; }
    }


   public void GetCart()
   {

   }
}

public interface ICart
{
   void GetCart();
   bool IsInfoExist { get; }
}
```

Comment: Then don't make `IsInfoExists`part of the interface

Comment: If you implement the `ICart` interface then you have the members on that interface.  By design.  Always.  If you don't want those members, don't implement that interface.  It sounds like what you want is a different interface.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle

Comment: That's going against the essence of interfaces.

Comment: So long as you declare your variables as `ICart`, **no amount** of trickery is going to hide the members.  You kinda end up painting yourself into a corner because on one hand you want to hide the implementation in the classes and yet when your main code goes to use `cart`, you have them declared as a `ICart` type!  So of course the clients of the code are going to know exactly what members are available

Comment: @Pikoh All methods and properties are same for both classes. but only IsInfoExist property part of Guest class. Is there a way to hide it from Member class. And I need that property :)

Comment: Once again. If `IsInfoExists` only must be in `Guest` class, remove it from the interface and leave it as is in the `Guest`class. A class implementing a interface must implement all methods in it, but it can have other methods that does not belong to the interface

Comment: @Pikoh I use ICart it must be. if I remove it. I just use Guest class to that. But I want to use ICart.

Comment: @PsyGnosis see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IsInfoExists` only must be in Guest class, remove it from the interface and leave it as is in the `Guest` class. 
A class implementing a interface must implement all methods in it, but it can have other methods that does not belong to the interface and are specific to that class. Is a nonsense having to implement `IsInfoExists` in the `Member` class only to hide it afterwards. So, it would be something like:

```
public interface ICart
{
     void GetCart();
}    

class Guest:ICart
{
    public bool IsInfoExist
    {
        get { return Session["guest_info"] != null; }
    }

    public void GetCart()
   {
   }
}

class Member:ICart
{ 
    public void GetCart()
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It seems the problem with this approach for you is that you are always using variables of type `ICart` and this way you can't access that method. But you can, you just have to cast it to the correct type,something like this:

```
ICart cart = new Guest();
ICart cart2 = new Member();

if (cart is Guest)
{
   bool info=((Guest)cart).IsInfoExist;
}

if (cart is Member)
{
   bool info=((Member)cart).IsInfoExist; //this won't compile as IsInfoExist is not in the Member class
}
```

Comment: you mean. You can't do that :).

Comment: Indeed. Edited :)

Answer (score 3):

By explicitly implementing the property:

```
bool ICart.IsInfoExist
{
    get { return Session["guest_info"] != null; }
}
```

If you have a `Member` or a `Guest` instance, it won't have an `IsInfoExist` unless you explicitly cast it to an `ICart`.

```
Member myMember = new Member();
bool test = myMember.IsInfoExist; // won't compile.
bool test1 = ((ICart) myMember).IsInfoExist; // will compile.
```

Comment: Actually, the only reason `bool test = myMember.IsInfoExist` won't compile is because you declared `myMember` as `var`.  If you declare it as `ICart` as per the OP it compiles perfectly.

Comment: Regarding your edit, not sure who's going to remember to type `bool test1 = ((ICart) myMember).IsInfoExist` all the time.  Not too readable.  Now if the simplest form _hid_ the members by default, and the complex form provided access to the _hidden_ member, then I would agree. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use two interfaces to accomplish that. Like `ICart` and `ICartInfo` for example. In this case you have a clear seperation and it would make your code cleaner and better to read.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way. 
Closest solution is

```
 [Obsolete("Only Guest Member", true)]
        public bool IsInfoExist
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
```

I'm gonna use this. Thanks